# Missing type arguments for generic type 'Future<dynamic>'. Try adding an explicit type, or remove implicit-dynamic from your analysis options file

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I resolve this issue without removing the implicit-dynamic form analysis options file?

Error:

[image]

My Code:

```
Future<void> _scrollToBottomOnKeyboardOpen() async {
        while (!isKeyboardVisible) {
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 50));
        }
    
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 250));
    
        await scrollController.animateTo(
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the specific type `void` and thus make it not generic:

`Future<void>.delayed(...)`